# Combining read replicas with tablespaces in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

When defining replica placement for tablespaces, are only hosts in the primary cluster considered? I'm noticing when I use placements that are only present in a read replica cluster, I'm getting `Not enough tablet servers` errors when trying to create a table in the tablespace.

I'd like to be able to take advantage of both tablespaces for row-level geo-partitioning and restricting the scope of data within a cluster, as well as read replicas to narrow the size of the primary cluster and improve write performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no primary nodes in a particular region covered by a tablespace, the data has nowhere to live and therefore no nodes replicating to read replicas.

Currently, you do need to have RF copies of the data in the primary region.

Also, we do not have support to customize read replica policies using tablespaces. Even if you have a custom placement policy for a table using tablespaces, it will continue to pick up the read-replica policy assigned by default to the cluster.

Supporting a custom read-replica configuration per tablespace, however, is in plan and tracked here: https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/8100